# Run an action on aspx page by querying data with LINQ on entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, linq, entity

Below is the source code content of `"DlmxRepository.cs"`; I don't know how to write this in the code part of my aspx page and how to control this data. To be honest; I have a dropdown list and a text box. I have a column named `DstId` and `DealerName` in my database. What I want is the value obtained from the drop-down menu and if the name written to the `textbox` is previously saved in my database, I want to show a warning on the screen "This data has been saved before"

How do I solve this problem?

```cs
public string[] getControl(int distId, string dealerName)
{
    using (var dx = Utility.getContext())
    {
        var entity = (from Dlmx in dx.Dlmxons
                      join name in dx.Dlmxons on Dlmx.DlmxDealer equals name.DlmxDealer
                      join dsid in dx.Dlmxons on Dlmx.DlmxId equals dsid.DlmxId
                      where Dlmx.DlmxDealer == dealerName && Dlmx.DlmxId == distId
                      select new
                      {
                          dealerName = dealerName,
                          distId = distId
                      }).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing data in ASP.NET MVC using LINQ - nuttiness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527187/passing-data-in-asp-net-mvc-using-linq-nuttiness)

Comment: For a start, you should remove these `join`s. They serve no purpose. Next, the code isn't complete. How do you get to returning `string[]`?