# What is the standard pattern to retrieve JOINed data from normalized tables?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-objects

I have the following simple "textbook" classes defined:

```
    public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Category { get; set; }
    }

    public class Category
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

The Category field in Product is an integer referencing the Id field in the Category class.  In the database, it would be a foreign key relationship between the Product and Category tables.

But my application would need to show the friendly name of the Category of a product.

**Q1**: Is it correct practice to define a new class as follows:

```
    public class ProductJ : Product
    {
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    }
```

And then, if I now have a method getProductsJ as follows:

```
    public class Test
    {
        public List<Category> Categories = new List<Category>() { ... };
        public List<Product> Products = new List<Product>() { ... };

        public List<ProductJ> getProductsJ()
        {
            var products = from p in Products
               join c in Categories on p.Category equals c.Id
               select new ProductJ { Id = p.Id, , Name = p.Name, CategoryName = c.Name }; //!
            return products.ToList();
        }
    }
```

**Q2**: Is the above the best way to retrieve a list of Products with Category names?

**Q3**: In the select statement (//!) is there a faster way to populate the fields of the base class Product linqwithout having to enter them one by one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could project the result of the join into an object that contains a reference to both the product and category.

```
public class Product
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int Category { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ProductCategory
{
  public Product Product { get; set; }
  public Category Category { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    List<Category> Categories = new List<Category>();
    List<Product> Products = new List<Product>();

    var products = from p in Products
                   join c in Categories on p.Category equals c.Id
                   select new ProductCategory { Product = p, Category = c };

    var list = products.ToList();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That answers Q3. But it would make it difficult to bind it to a table grid.

Comment: Why would it make binding difficult? Could you use sub-property bindings? Example: list[0].Category.Name?

Comment: I'm with @thedugas here, I'm not sure how this would make it difficult to bind to a table grid. I have easily bound IEnumberable & IList to datagrids before.

Comment: Sorry, pardon my ignorance.  Forgot that grid fields can be mapped one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Does each book belongs to one category, or can it belong to more than one category in your case? because if a book belongs to one category then you can simply move the category name in the Book Table. also i will suggest to have a look on

[MVC LINQ to SQL Table Join Record Display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278941/mvc-linq-to-sql-table-join-record-display)

Comment: Answer to your question is just one Category per Product. (BTW it's Product not Book but never mind.) But doing what you suggest would renormalize the tables and make it difficult to maintain the list of categories. Isn't what I am doing on the data organization the AdventureWorks way?

Comment: I meant "de-normalize".   (Swype on Android always try to put words on my behalf.)

Comment: Have u checked the link which i mentioned above? i think that post contains one of the good apporach